# C#: Checking for duplicate elements in XML

Tags: c#, xml

I want to check for duplicate elements in XML. Please help!

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<List>
  <Email_Entry></Email_Entry>
  <Email_Entry EmailID="qw@gmail.com" />
  <Email_Entry EmailID="qw@gmail.com" />
  <Email_Entry EmailID="qw@gmail.com" />
  <Email_Entry EmailID="qw@gmail.com" />
  <Email_Entry EmailID="shssh@gmail.com" />
</List>
```

aspx.cs:

```
protected void btnEmailSubscribe_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    string EmailID = txtEmailSubscribe.Text;
    string FILE_PATH = Server.MapPath("~/Logs/SubscribedEmails.xml");

    XDocument Emailxml = XDocument.Load(FILE_PATH);
    var EmailExist = Emailxml.Descendants("Email_Entry")
        .Any(x => (string)x.Element("EmailID") == txtEmailSubscribe.Text);
    if (EmailExist)
    {
        lblEmail.Text = "EmailID already exist";
    }
    else
    {
        Emailxml.Root.Add(new XElement("Email_Entry",
                   new XAttribute("EmailID", EmailID)
               ));
        Emailxml.Save(FILE_PATH);
        lblEmail.Text = "Subscribed Successfully";
    }            
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check attribute value instead of element:

```
var EmailExist = Emailxml.Descendants("Email_Entry")
        .Any(x => x.Attribute("EmailID").Value == txtEmailSubscribe.Text);
```

Comment: Should be Where instead of Any.  Any will return true/false,

Comment: @jdweng when I check email exists I use `Any`

Answer (score 0):

var xml = File.ReadAllText("your xml file path");

```
        var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.LoadXml(xml);

        var dups = xmlDoc.FirstChild.ChildNodes
            .Cast<XmlNode>()
            .Where(n=>n.Attributes.Count>0)
            .GroupBy(n => n.Attributes["EmailID"].Value)
            .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
            .SelectMany(g => g.ToList())
            .ToList();
```